# Webstorm, релативные пути

Tags: html, css, phpstorm, ide, webstorm

Доброго времени суток! Работаю с Gulp, мне необходимо использовать релативные пути, так как работаю в папке `src`, а проект билдится в `dest` и пути желательно прописывать к этой папке. В `css` по двойному нажатию `ctrl + space` прописывается путь к картинке, например, но без `../` в самом начале пути. Хотелось бы также с `.html` файлом. Хотелось бы, чтобы было как на скриншоте: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: UPD: по тройному нажатию ctrl + space прописывается путь к картинке, например, но путь вставляется без ../ в самом начале. В html наоборот хорошо прописывается путь, но он вставляет лишнее ../dest, но опять же нужно просто ../. Можно как-то это поправить?